How to swap right-click+drag and mouse wheel actions in PyMOL?
I'm trying to customize the mouse controls in PyMOL. Specifically, I would like to reverse the actions of right-click+drag and the mouse wheel. Is there a way to swap these controls or customize the mouse interaction settings?
I tried looking for an option directly in the PyMOL interface to swap the controls, but I couldn't find any. I also attempted using PyMOL commands to customize the mouse settings, but they didn't work as expected. I was hoping to find a straightforward way to swap the right-click+drag action with the mouse wheel, but so far, I haven't been successful.

my attempt:
import time

import pymol

from pymol import cmd, stored


print('########## PYMOL VERSION ##########################################')
print('         ',  cmd.get_version() )
print('###################################################################')


# pymol.finish_launching()

pymol.finish_launching(['pymol', '-q', '-W', '1200', '-H', '900'])


time.sleep(3)


cmd.fab('AAAGGAAGGVVPCAGCA', 'peptide')


print('\n\nbutton_mode :    ', cmd.get('button_mode'))
print('\n\nbutton_mode_name :    ', cmd.get('button_mode_name'))

cmd.button('R', 'None', 'Clip')

cmd.button('Wheel', 'None', 'MovZ')

I used Button PyMOLWiki or PyMOL Command reference
unfortunately I cannot get the button settings with a command like :
print('\n\nbutton_mode :    ', cmd.get('button_mode'))
print('\n\nbutton_mode_name :    ', cmd.get('button_mode_name'))

using Get cmd.Get PyMOLWiki and settings from Settings PyMOLWiki
but could be me not knowing enough
